# back button shows blank screen

Tags: android, facebook, webview

When I press the 'back' button of a mobile-phone it shows me a blank page. When I again press the 'back' button it then shows me the main page of the application. I want to get to the `mainActivity` page on first back press.

`mainActivity` code:

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.text.style.SuperscriptSpan;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.os.Build;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

Button b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7;
EditText e1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.call1);
    e1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.call);

    b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String no=e1.getText().toString();
            Intent call=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            call.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+no));
            startActivity(call);

            }
    });

    b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.sens_sms);
    b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent sendsms=new   
Intent(getApplicationContext(),waytosms.class);
            startActivity(sendsms);
        }
    });
    b3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.facebook);
    b3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent facebook=new Intent(MainActivity.this,facebook.class);
            startActivity(facebook);
            finish();

            }
    });
    b4=(Button)findViewById(R.id.gmail);
    b4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent facebook=new Intent(MainActivity.this,gmail.class);
            startActivity(facebook);

        }
    });
    b5=(Button)findViewById(R.id.utube);
    b5.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent facebook=new Intent(MainActivity.this,utube.class);
            startActivity(facebook);

        }
    });
    b6=(Button)findViewById(R.id.google);
    b6.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent facebook=new Intent(MainActivity.this,google.class);
            startActivity(facebook);

        }
    });
    b7=(Button)findViewById(R.id.twitter);
    b7.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent facebook=new Intent(MainActivity.this,twitter.class);
            startActivity(facebook);

        }
    });
 }



}
```

This is the Facebook class I have used here with webview to open the Facebook page:

```
public class facebook extends Activity{
WebView facebook;

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.facebook);

    facebook=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webfacebook);
    facebook.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    facebook.loadUrl("https://facebook.com");
}
```

Here I have implemented `onbackPressed()` and called `finished()` The `onbackpressed` method isn't affecting this at all.

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onBackPressed();
    finish();
    Intent i=new Intent(facebook.this,MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);

}
}
```

> 1> first is main activity page where there are icon  of social sites when 
>   i click on facebook icon it will open facebook as 2nd facebookActivity page,3> when i clicked back it will open a blank page and4>. nd when i again press back button it will opened the main activity page...

Comment: First of all you have to  call finish method after startactivity or no need to call startactivity just call finish method in backpress it will automatically resume the last activity from stack.

Comment: why are you overridding onBackPressed()? Standard Android behaviour is to return to the calling activity automatically when back is pressed.

Comment: @RavindMaurya none of these worked .........   see my edit question

Answer (score 1):

Change your `onBackPressed()` method like this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onBackPressed();
    finish();
    Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```